# Mocking in Swift for XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xctest

I am writing test cases for my project which is mix up with Objective C as well as Swift code. I am aware about OCMock framework which I have used previously for mocking/Stubbing for writing Test cases in Objective C.
But I googled and found that it doesn't support fully for swift, since it is based on Objective C runtime. 
I am trying to write test cases in swift language. Is there way I can do mocking/Stubbing for service level layer. For eg.

```
 func getPersonData(id:String, success: (ReponseEnum) -> Void, failure: (error: NSError) -> Void) {


                let requestPara:NSDictionary =  ["id": id]

                let manager: MyRequestManager = MyRequestManager.sharedManager()

                //MyRequestManager is nothing but AFNetworking class 
                let jsonRequest
                /// Service request creation code here


                // Service Call

                manager.POST(url, parameters: jsonRequest, success: { (task: NSURLSessionDataTask!, responseObject: AnyObject!) -> () in

                    // Some business logic
                    //success block call
                    success (successEnum)



                }) {(task: NSURLSessionDataTask!, error: NSError!) -> () in

                    // failure block call
                    failure (failureEnum)

                }
    }
```

Here how to mock post method call for dummy responseObject So I can write test cases?

Comment: Here we just create our own mock objects as and when we need them. As of yet, we've not found a 'tool' to do it for us and its actually rather simple. For stubbing network calls, we use Mockingjay --> https://github.com/kylef/Mockingjay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **dependency injection** to be able to mock the `POST` method.

Your class, where you defined the `getPersonData(id:success:failure)` method, needs to accept MyRequestManager as a parameter in constructor:

```
class MyClass {
    private let requestManager: MyRequestManager

    init(requestManager: MyRequestManager) {
        self.requestManager = requestManager
    }
}
```

Then you create a mock for your request manager:

```
class MockMyRequestManager: MyRequestManager {

   // not sure about correct method signature
   override func POST(url: NSURL, parameters: [String: AnyObject], success: (() -> Void)?) {
       //implement any custom logic that you want to expect when executing test
   }
}
```

And in the tests you initialise your class with a mock:

```
let myClass = MyClass(requestManager: MockMyRequestManager())
```

You can find more details about dependency injection here:
http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html